# How do I open ContextMenu with a Button

Tags: android, button, contextmenu

I'd like to show a `context_menu` when a user click on a `Button` but I'm encountering some problems. For some reason the menu is not appearing, maybe there's something I'm missing. Can you help me please?
That's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    registerForContextMenu(btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.showContextMenu();
        }
    });

}
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int i = item.getItemId();
    if (i == R.id.share) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Leggi");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.chooser_title)));
        return true;
    } else {
        return onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return true;
}
```

and this is my `context_menu` in `R.menu`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="Condividi"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/web"
    android:title="Mostra articolo"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/add"
    android:title="Aggiungi nei Preferiti"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the  `app:showAsAction="never"` to `android:showAsAction="never"` perhaps ?
(or just remove it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried but this is not the reason. Still nothing

Comment: I tried copying your code into a simple project and it works for me, but I had to remove the showAsAction attributes to get the menu resource to compile.

Comment: Perhaps try cleaning your project ?

Comment: By cleaning you mean to create a new project and copy what I have here?

Comment: Try deleting the contents of the bin and the gen folder and then rebuilding the project.

Comment: I created a new project and it works, but now I see that this ContextMenu is not what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use openContextMenu instead of showContextMenu.

```
registerForContextMenu(btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openContextMenu(v);
    }
});
```

Comment: The result is the same, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code
code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        registerForContextMenu(btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            btn.showContextMenu();

        }
    }); 

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        menu.add(0,1,0,"copy");
        menu.add(0,2,0,"paste");
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

}
```

Comment: Still nothing. I can't see where's the problem